# Error: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll

Tags: c#, uwp, voice-recognition

I'm writing a UWP C# app for my Raspberry Pi. I want to create a continuous recognition session, but every time my program hits `await recognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync();` it fails due to this error.

I've tried adding lines to my manifest file such as `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />` but to no avail.

How should I go about calling this method? I've set up prerequisites like a grammar.xml file for calling it, but I still can't find the issue:

```
const string SRGS_FILE = "Grammar\\grammar.xml";
    SpeechRecognizer recognizer;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Unloaded += MainPage_Unloaded;
        initializeSpeechRecognizer();
    }

    private async void initializeSpeechRecognizer()
    {
        // Initialize recognizer
        recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer();

        // Set event handlers
        recognizer.StateChanged += RecognizerStateChanged;
        recognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.ResultGenerated += RecognizerResultGenerated;
        txbSpeech.Text += "Event handlers set\n";

        // Load Grammer file constraint
        string fileName = String.Format(SRGS_FILE);
        StorageFile grammarContentFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(fileName);
        txbSpeech.Text += "Grammar file constraint loaded\n";

        SpeechRecognitionGrammarFileConstraint grammarConstraint = new SpeechRecognitionGrammarFileConstraint(grammarContentFile);

        // Add to grammer constraint
        recognizer.Constraints.Add(grammarConstraint);
        txbSpeech.Text += "Grammar constraint added\n";

        // Compile grammer
        SpeechRecognitionCompilationResult compilationResult = await recognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();
        txbSpeech.Text += "Grammar compiled\n";

        txbSpeech.Text += ("Status: " + compilationResult.Status.ToString() + "\n");

        // If successful, display the recognition result.
        if (compilationResult.Status == SpeechRecognitionResultStatus.Success)
        {
            txbSpeech.Text += ("Result: " + compilationResult.ToString()) + "\n";

            // The line below fails
            await recognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            txbSpeech.Text += ("Status: " + compilationResult.Status + "\n");
        }
    }

    private void RecognizerResultGenerated(SpeechContinuousRecognitionSession session, SpeechContinuousRecognitionResultGeneratedEventArgs args)
    {
        // Output debug strings
        txbSpeech.Text += (args.Result.Status.ToString() + "\n");
        txbSpeech.Text += (args.Result.Text + "\n");
    }

    // Recognizer state changed
    private void RecognizerStateChanged(SpeechRecognizer sender, SpeechRecognizerStateChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        //txbSpeech.Text += ("Speech recognizer state: " + args.State.ToString() + "\n");
    }
```

Comment: Do you have the microphone capability declared? Also did you check if the recognizer supports your language? (I don't think the IoT build ships with any recognizers languages) -- look at the various properties of the class.

Comment: I'm not sure how to declare microphone capabilties... Would I have to add a line to the Manifest? Also, I will make sure to implement a line telling it to use english. I had one earlier, but I started from scratch and it was lost in the process.

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio, just double-click the appxmanifest and one of the tabs is **Capabilities**.